# Allow emojis in textformfield in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to allow emojis as input string in text form field flutter.

Text form field should allow only text and emojis. How to do it.

Comment: add  keyboardType: TextInputType.textAndEmoji, in text  field

Comment: he getter 'textAndEmoji' isn't defined for the type 'TextInputType'

Comment: getting above error when I tried to add in TextFormField –

Comment: check this. there is no option for emojis https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputType-class.html

Comment: which flutter version you have  in that   showing error   then you  need  use pluging

Comment: the textInputType property is only available in Flutter 2.0 or later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252040/discussion-between-parthis-and-wolfsoft-developer).

Answer (score 0):

```
class EmojiTextField extends StatefulWidget { 
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  String? _validateInput(String input) {
    final RegExp regex = RegExp(
      r'^[\u0020-\u007E\u00A0-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u0250-\u02AF\u0300-\u03FF]*$',
      );
if (!regex.hasMatch(input)) {
  return 'Please enter only text and emojis';
}
return null;
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
child: TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Enter text or emojis',
        errorText: _validateInput(_controller.text),
      ),
    ),
 );
}
```

Comment: The getter 'textAndEmoji' isn't defined for the type 'TextInputType'. (Documentation)

Comment: getting above error when I tried to add in TextFormField

Comment: also we do not have option for emoji. check in this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputType-class.html

Comment: then use that package https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter/install after  some time I change  my  answer (that time  I  can not   edit my  ans)

Comment: your updated answer is work on that case, when user entered some wrong characters and error occures. In my case, I am not even able to input emoji in text form field. when I type keypad does not allow me to click on emoji.

Comment: which futter version you use

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following package:

```
emoji_picker_flutter
```

https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter